# Binary Tree method instance

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, binary-tree

When I was coding a generic "BinaryTree", I needed a method to sum the values of all left subtrees in a tree. This method should return an integer value in a recursive way. However, when I tried to add the root value to the summation, I couldn't cast the "T" value to "int" because the "T" value is incompatible. I created a child class that extends from "BinaryTree" using integer type. In this case, I needed to create the method in my parent class because the recursive call needs to use the method in the parent class and it is a bit annoying me. I think that there is another way to avoid this behavior. Is there a way to avoid creating the method in my parent class?

Binary Tree Class:

```
public class BinaryTree<T> {

protected T root= null;
protected BinaryTree<T> left= null, right= null;

 //All binary tree here

Integer sumLeft() {
    return 0;
}
```

Binary Tree Integer

```
public class BinaryTreeInteger extends BinaryTree<Integer> {
//All code here

Integer sumLeft() {
    int suma = 0;       
    if (isLeaf()) {            
        return getRaiz();
    }
    if (left != null) {

            if (!left.EsHoja()) {
                suma += left.getRaiz() + left.sumLeft();
            } else {
                suma += left.sumLeft();
            }              

    }
    if (right != null && !right.isLeaf()) {

            suma += right.sumLeft();                

    }
    return suma;
}

}

}
```

Comment: A *generic* binary tree cannot sum values, because the values are not numbers. Thinking otherwise will just give you headaches. Rethink what you're trying to do, because you're off-track before you even left the gate. --- Also, walking down the left side of a tree should not be a recursive method. A simple loop can do it, and will not cause stack overflow.

Comment: @Anil Was that "agreed" directed at me? I'm not the OP. I don't need any help.